# Does Svelte have render functions or custom template helpers?

Tags: svelte

Svelte ships with things like [#if](https://svelte.dev/docs#if) and [#each](https://svelte.dev/docs#each). How can the user do arbitrary template logic?

For example, React and Vue both enable [using functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) to define a UI tree, and Ember has [Handlebars helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.4.0/tutorial/hbs-helper/).

### Update

To give a more specific example, how would I implement "every third row should have a dark-gray background unless it contains a photo?"

> See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352970/does-svelte-have-render-functions-or-custom-template-helpers?noredirect=1#comment109735455_61352970)

Comment: What kind of logic, specifically?

Comment: I was thinking about things like: every third row should have a dark-gray background unless it contains a photo.

Comment: You can easily do stuff like that with the existing primitives: `{#each makeEveryThirdRowDarkGrayUnlessItHasAPhoto(rows) as row}`, or `class:darkbg={isThirdRowAndDoesntHavePhoto(row,i)}`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have the @html directive which allows you to inject html in normal strings. Basically, when using the directive, characters like < and > are not escaped. I created a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1cb97f8be82e4421a740afa046816f14?version=3.20.1) for you.

```
<script>
const text = "This is some <strong>bold</strong> statement"
</script>

<div>{text}</div> // This is some <strong>bold</strong> statement
<div>{@html text}</div> // This is some bold statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to updated question..
You put logic directly in svelte..
Here is [a repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/c2e6f798e2a14005a203126881c74d94?version=3.49.0) that implements the logic you decribed.

```
<script>
    let things = [
        {name: 'item1', photo: false},
        {name: 'item2', photo: false},
        {name: 'item3', photo: false},
        {name: 'item4', photo: false},
        {name: 'item5', photo: false},
        {name: 'item6', photo: true},
    ];
</script>

<style>
    .dark-gray-background {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #ffffff
    }
</style>

<ul>
{#each things as thing, index}
    <li class="{(!((index+1) % 3) && !thing.photo) ? 'dark-gray-background' : ''}">{thing.name}</li>
{/each}
</ul>
```